# Going from Python to C# trouble with syntax that isn't showing error

Tags: c#, python, .net

Trying to rewrite a python script into a C# console program for finding percentages out of raw numbers.  Every time I run this, even if I replace high/low_water with hardcoded numbers, percent always comes out 0, not sure what I'm missing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the High Water Mark? ");
        int high_water = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int percent = 0;

        while(percent < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the Low Water Mark? ");
            int low_water = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            percent = (low_water / high_water) / 100;
            Console.WriteLine(percent);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Operation Complete");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get percentage I believe that you need to use multiply instead of divide;
and you need to use `double` type to get the `ratio` to prevent loss of precision (decimal points) before converting it to percentage.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the High Water Mark? ");
        int high_water = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int percent = 0;

        while (percent < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the Low Water Mark? ");
            int low_water = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double ratio = (double)low_water / high_water;
            percent = (int) Math.Round(ratio * 100);
            Console.WriteLine(percent);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Operation Complete");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, the division was a result of me screwing myself up typing.  It's been a while since I've played in C#, changing the variables to double worked.  Again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All of your numbers are declared as integers so integer arithmetic is applied.

So if `low` is lower than `high` then `low/high` is 0.

I also guess you calculation was in error.

I think your calc should be

`percent = (100.0*high)-(100.0*low);`

And`percent` defined as

`var percent=0.0;`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate percentage 100 should be multiplied, not divided. Dividing with 100 will always give value less than 1.

Also, you are using integer for percent. In this case it is getting rounded to 0.